# How to prove that two intersecting simple polygons must either have intersecting edges or one must be contained in the other.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, trigonometry, geometric-topology

I am a computer scientist who is building a 2D collision detection engine that can detect whether or not two arbitrary simple polygons collide/overlap/intersect.
Intuitively, one can identify that, for a collision to occur, there must be either an intersection between their edges or one of the polygons must be completely contained in the other.
[See visual example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHzQ5.png)

However, I would like to formalise this 'intuition' (which is hopefully correct) using set theory and topology.

The two simple polygons can be represented by two simply connected subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The conjecture I came up with goes as follows:

$A \cap B = \emptyset \iff \partial  A \cap \partial B = \emptyset \land A \not\subset B \land B \not\subset A $

Or in words: A and B do not intersect if and only if their boundaries (i.e. edges) do not intersect and neither one is a subset of the other.

I feel like this is such a simple statement that a proof must already exists somewhere. But my lack of knowledge in this branch of mathematics does not allow me to search effectively for one.

Can someone point me to a proof (if it exists)? I would like be able to reference it.

PS: The closest thing i found is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728625/when-do-two-overlapping-sets-in-mathbbrn-have-a-common-boundary-point-whe), but here they are limited to convex shapes. My conjecture, meanwhile, should hold true for any pair of non-convex simple polygons.

Comment: What if they are completely disjoint?

Comment: In that case there is no collision. However, this is impractical to compute and is the reason I need the alternativie 'definition'. Computing edge intersections and full containment quite straightforward (see [line-line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) and [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) test)

Comment: Are your polygons convex? That is an easy case (simple properties of convex figures will do what you want). If not the intersections could be multiple.

Comment: The polygons are non-convex. Also important to note is that I only need a binary answer on the question of intersection. They either intersect (in any way) or they do not. I am not interested in the "how".

Answer (score 2):

Parthi's answer is exactly right (but only for a better-expressed question).

Consider the sets $$
A = \{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}\\
A = \{(x, y) \mid (x-2)^2 + y^2 <= 1 \}
$$
These are simply connected, and their boundaries (the unit circle at the origin and the unit circle at $(2, 0)$ intersect at $(1,0)$. But $A \cap B$ is empty.

In generalizing "(filled) polygons" to "simply connected sets", you overshot a bit. At the very least, you probably want simply-connected  *closed* sets, so that they contain their boundaries to avoid this example. Indeed, you probably want to say that each of $A$ and $B$ is  a "Jordan curve, together with the bounded component of its complement".

As a computer scientist who used to do topology, let me just advise that this stuff is probably trickier than you think. (There is, for instance, and entire book called "Counterexamples in Topology" filled with apparently reasonable statements that are false.)

One challenge with your definition, even in the amended form above, is that testing whether two segments intersect is no easier than testing whether two numbers are equal, because of the ugly case where you have, say, two different-size squares that share a vertical edge -- you have to test for equality of (probably) floating-point numbers, whose challenges I'm sure you know all about. Transverse intersections are comparatively better, although if one of the edges is very short (like $(0,x)$ and $(0, y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are adjacent floats), even that can be a problem.

Most CS folks know about the wonders and perils of floating-point numbers; when you combine those with the wonders and perils of topology, things get difficult.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of the fp challenges. The engine is designed for use in heuristics to solve 2d irregular nesting problems. So in cases where there could be a error due fp arithmetic, the engine just errs on the side of caution and returns a collision (possibly falsely). Do you suggest alternatives for formalising my statement (slightly)?

Comment: Sure. Replace $A$ and $B$ being (filled) polygons "each of 
 and 
 is a Jordan curve, together with the bounded component of its complement." Once you do that, Nicholas's answer gives you the proof that you need (indeed, the Jordan-ness of the curves is really all that his proof requires). BTW, once you allow yourself the "slack" of false positives, some properties you might want to rely on may become false (e.g., if closed polygon C is contained in A, and C intersects B, then A must also intersect B). (I'm not sure that one is violated, but showing it isn't requires proof.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in two dimensions, here is a (probably overkill) proof. By the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), the boundary of one of your polygons divides the plane into two regions. The boundary of the other polygon is a continuous curve, which if it does not intersect the first boundary, must lie completely in one of the two regions. But these possibilities can be ruled out as one of the polygons being contained in the other (or the two being completely disjoint).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A, B \subsetneq \mathbb R^2$ be nonempty closed sets (as are polygons). The *interior* $A^o$ of $A$ is union of all open sets contained in $A$; the *boundary* is $\partial A = A\setminus A^o$. We will also assume that the boundaries are curves, i.e. that there are continuous functions $\gamma_A, \gamma_B : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(\gamma_A) = \partial A$, $\mathrm{Im}(\gamma_B) = \partial B$, $\gamma_A(0) = \gamma_A(1)$, and $\gamma_B(0) = \gamma_B(1)$.

The direction $\implies$ is obvious. To prove $\impliedby$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $A\cap B \ne \varnothing$. Because the boundaries do not intersect, any $x \in A\cap B$ must be in one of the following sets:
$$
  A^o\cap B^o,\quad A^o\cap\partial B,\quad \partial A\cap B^o.
$$
If the first case is true, then $x$ is contained in an open set contained in $A\cap B$; so if it's true for *all* $x$ then $A\cap B$ is open; but $A\cap B$ is also closed, which is a contradiction because there are no nontrivial clopen sets in $\mathbb R^2$.

So WLOG there is some $x \in A^o\cap \partial B$, and $U = \gamma_B^{-1}(A^o)$ is a nonempty open set. If $U \ne [0,1]$ then $(a, b)\cup(b, a) \subseteq U$ for some $a, b$ with $b \not\in U$. Then $\gamma_B(b) = \lim_{t\to b}\gamma_B(t)$ is in the closure of $A^o$, namely $A$, but also not in $A^o$, so it's actually in $\partial A\cap\partial B$. This is a contradiction, so $U = [0,1]$.

Thus $\partial B \subseteq A^o$, and I hope you will allow me to make the leap that this means $B \subseteq A$, which is a contradiction to the initial hypotheses. Thus $A\cap B$ is empty.